# Prove that $\mathbf{F}'(0)=\mathbf{f}'(\mathbf{c};\mathbf{u})$, the directional derivative of $\mathbf{f}$ at $\mathbf{c}$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Prove that $\mathbf{F}'(0)=\mathbf{f}'(\mathbf{c};\mathbf{u})$, the directional derivative of $\mathbf{f}$ at $\mathbf{c}$, where $f(x,y)=x^{2}-y^{2}$ and $\mathbf{F}(t)=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c}+t\mathbf{u})$.

Here's my attempt:

$\mathbf{F}'(0)=\mathbf{f}'(\mathbf{c})=(f_{1}'(\mathbf{c}),...,f_{m}'(\mathbf{c}))$

$=(D_{1}f_{1}(\mathbf{c}),...,D_{1}f_{m}(\mathbf{c}))$

$=\left ( \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f_{1}(\mathbf{c}+h\mathbf{u}_{1})-f_{1}(\mathbf{c})}{h},...,\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f_{m}(\mathbf{c}+h\mathbf{u}_{1})-f_{m}(\mathbf{c})}{h}\right )$, where $\mathbf{u}_{1}$ is the standard unit vector.

$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c}+h\mathbf{u}_{1})-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c})}{h}=\mathbf{f}'(\mathbf{c};\mathbf{u}_{1})$

Then let $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{u}_{1}$? My attempt seems wrong. Any tips are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\mathbf{F}(t) = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c} + t\mathbf{u})$ is a real-valued function, hence, by definition of the derivative at $t = 0$ we have
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{F}'(0) &= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\mathbf{F}(0+h) - \mathbf{F}(0)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{t\to0} \frac{\mathbf{F}(t) - \mathbf{F}(0)}{t} \\
&= \lim_{t\to0} \frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c} + t\mathbf{u}) - \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c})}{t}
\end{align}$$ 
and this is precisely the definition of the directional derivative $\mathbf{f}'(\mathbf c; \mathbf u)$.